# Determination of transmembrane domain limits using multiple prediction tools

Tags: membrane-protein, tools

Integral membrane proteins are proteins that have at least one transmembrane (TM) segment.
I performed predictions of TM domains using three tools: ProtScale, ΔG predictor 1.0, TOPCONS.

For example, the results in terms of aminoacid positions for the TM1 domain were as follows:

- **ProtScale**: 37-55
- **ΔG predictor**: 37-55
- **TOPCONS**: 36-56

The limits of the predicted TM domains can be used for drawing the topology of this protein.

For this purpose, we need to have representative limits from these results.

**Statistically speaking:**

- which values should be chosen?
- should we calculate a mean : (37+37+36)/3=36.67 knowing that these values correspond to aminoacid positions and 36.67 doesn't mean anything?

How can I use these results (37, 37, 36) to determine the limit corresponding to the 1st aminoacid of TM1 segment?

Comment: How big is the protein? Normally TMDs are at the 3' end of the protein.

Comment: The protein has 426 aminoacids. TM1 is the first TM segment, from the N-terminal domain.

Answer (score 0):

The variation you are seeing are minor differences in estimates in the transmembrane domain, these are usually modelled by hydrophobicity and are accurate predictions. If you look at the secondary/tertiary structure you might see alpha helices which will 'burrow' into the membrane. The region in this particular question is a small domain however, but the position is 'about right'.

Thus question is whether 1 amino acid at 5' and 3' site is inside or outside the membrane - I think this is overthinking. Edge-effects are common in any estimate and 1 amino isn't bad variation at all. To double check have a look at the Kyte-Doolittle index on the Expasy website (which is one of the first), and [TMHMM](https://services.healthtech.dtu.dk/service.php?TMHMM-2.0). Finally, you need to check the crystal structure if available.

What does puzzle me is the apparent absence of a 3' GPI anchor, but I dunno the biological system so ain't for me to comment.